# calling another php function after jquery post

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am performing the jquery POST correctly, however I would like to call another PHP function inside the controller. **EDIT** The code below works fine....I'm just an idiot. Someone close this please.

Here is the setup:

```
class controller extends CI_Controller {

  function con1() {
  //retrieve post variable
  $this->con2()
  }

  function con2() {
  //do something
  $this->my_model->get_results() //fails
  }

}
```

Jquery POSTS to `con1`, however it will fail when i do `$this->con2()`. Is there anyway I can get this to work? Also, is it possible to call a model once jquery posts the data?

Thanks

Comment: It should work by default...why don't you post the whole code here? That way we can see what's wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear what you aren't able to do, but why are you juggling with controller's methods, when model are done just for that?
The purpose of a Model is being something re-usable, so why don't you call it right in `con1()` method?

```
class Controller extends CI_Controller {

  function con1() {
  $this->load->model('my_model');
  //retrieve post variable
  echo $this->my_model->get_results(); 
  }
}
```

Also, post variable are available to Models also, if you want to grab their values there.
If you expand your answer with further details I'll edit and update my question, so far it's just a bit of a guessing on what's wrong. The code I showed **should** work, provided the `get_result()` method actually returns something (which you need to echo out).

If by "how do I call a function within a model" means how you call a model's method inside another model's method, well, it works like any php class method's call, `$this->other_method();`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tend to strictly put database related material in the Model. If I reuse code that is quite substantial, I generally place it in a library. I finally got xdebug to work, but it looks like `get_result()` causes problems with Codeigniter's session.

Comment: @Justin Model are not exlusively for database, but for any code elaboration that can make them usable on different situations; you're right about using a library sometimes, and in that case my suggestion is still valid: instead of redirecting to another controller's method, just call the library right where you need it

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used codeigniter but I suspect redirecting to con2 within con1 with the post array would fix the issue.

Comment: Yes, the redirect allows me to call another function, however all context will be lost. This redirect works within controllers, but how would I achieve the same effect in models which are not URL accessible?